# How to avoid onCameraIdle when controller.animateCamera be called?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I used Google Map in my flutter project.

The code look like:

```
GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      markers: Set.of(positionsList),
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        if (!_mapController.isCompleted) {
          _mapController.complete(controller);
        }
      },
      onCameraIdle: () {
        postRequestToUpdatePositionsList();
      },
    );
```

When i darg the map , `postRequestToUpdateMarkersList()` will be called to update the positonsList
And i have a ListView to show the detail of the positonsList.
The map will move the camera to the position which i choosed in the ListView.

That code look like:

```
onTap: () {
      CameraPosition cameraPos = CameraPosition(target: nowPosition, zoom: defaultZoom);
      controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPos));
}
```

When i choose one of the ListView,the camera moved and the `postRequestToUpdateMarkersList()` will be called. Thats what i don't want to.

Is there anything to avoid calling onCameraIdle when i switch the target of ListView and call onCameraIdle when i darg the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a boolean to check if the camera moved from the onClick or a dragEvent

```
bool isOnTapMove = false;
```

In your onTap you set this to true:

```
isOnTapMove = true;
```

Check this variable inside your onCameraIdle.

If it is **false**, you call your postRequestToUpdatePositionsList function.

If it is **true**, you just reset it to false.

```
if(isOnTapMove){
 isOnTapMove = false;
}else{
postRequestToUpdatePositionsList();
}
```

Comment: I had think about adding a boolean flag to check the click or dragEvent before,  but i didn't consider the timing of resetting the flag clearly.Your answer really help me a lot, thank you!